# Thumbnail object has url, but no content

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Using the Microsoft Graph C# SDK v1.13. I am able to retrieve an `IDriveItemThumbnailsCollectionPage` for my `DriveItem`.  With that page, I can get the first `ThumbnailSet`.  That `ThumbnailSet` has a small, medium and large Thumbnail object.

Each of those Thumbnail objects appears to have a valid URL for the thumbnail.  However, none of the `.Content` (Stream) properties are valid...they are all `NULL`.

Ex:

```
IDriveItemThumbnailsCollectionPage page = await client
    .Me
    .Drive
    .Items[this.Id]
    .Thumbnails
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

if ((page != null) && (page.CurrentPage != null) && (page.CurrentPage.Count > 0)) {
    ThumbnailSet thumbs = page.CurrentPage.FirstOrDefault();
    if (thumbs != null) {
        if ((minHeight != null) && (minHeight.HasValue) && (minWidth != null) && (minWidth.HasValue)) {
            if ((minHeight > 48) || (minWidth > 48)) {
                Thumbnail thumb = thumbs.Medium;
                thumbStream = thumb?.Content;
            }
        }

        if (thumbStream == null)
            thumbStream = thumbs?.Small?.Content;
    }
}
```

How do I get one of these Thumbnail's content streams with the SDK?

Using VS debugger to look at the returned vars, "thumbs" is populated with size and URL, but attempting to retrieve the Content is always NULL.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I strongly recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on getting started. In particular, please include a code sample showing how you're calling the API, the result you're getting back, and what steps you've already tried.

Comment: Sure, Marc.  I didn't think I left that much to be inferred.  I will update my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`Thumbnail.Url` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/thumbnail?view=odsp-graph-online) is used to store *the URL to fetch the thumbnail* content, probably the easiest option to download thumbnail content would be like this:

```
var page = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items[itemId].Thumbnails.Request().GetAsync();
var thumbnailSet = page.FirstOrDefault();
var thumbnail = thumbnailSet?.Medium;
using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    var content = client.DownloadData(thumbnail.Url);  //download it as a byte array

    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(targetFileName, content); //save into file
}
```

**Option 2**

Another option would be to utilize the following endpoint ([from docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_list_thumbnails?view=odsp-graph-online#retrieve-thumbnail-binary-content)):

```
GET /me/drive/items/{item-id}/thumbnails/{thumb-id}/{size}/content
```

Here is an example for [`msgraph-sdk-dotnet`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet):

```
//1.get thumbnail metadata (similar to previous example)
var requestUrl = $"{graphClient.BaseUrl}/me/drive/items/{itemId}/thumbnails/{thumbnailId}/{thumbnailSize}";
var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
await graphClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(message);
var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(message);
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var thumbnail = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Thumbnail>(content);

//2.get thumbnail content
requestUrl = $"{graphClient.BaseUrl}/me/drive/items/{itemId}/thumbnails/{thumbnailId}/{thumbnailSize}/content";
message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
await graphClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(message);
response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(message);
var bytesContent = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

Comment: This may be a valid way to go.  (I will have to get the AccessToken and add that as an Authorization Header.)  However, the "Content" property indicates it does that for me...so it would be a bug.  Thanks for the feedback and option!

Comment: Yes, this is one of the best ways to do it.  I found this yesterday too.  (The generated URLs require a different AuthToken or something - they will not allow my current - and valid - AccessToken to get the images.)  There is also another way that I found in one of the "miscellaneous tests", and it seems convoluted.  Either way, the .Content property is entirely inaccurate and incorrectly documented.  Marking this as the answer.  Thank you! @Vadim